# Are there any Vedic/Hinduism scriptures which talk about intelligence completely?

Tags: scripture

Has anyone come across any such texts/book which talk about on how to improve intelligence? Tried reading [Shiva Swarodaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Swarodaya_/_Swara_Yoga), it was awesome. Wanted to know if there are any other similar texts.

Comment: Hey, can you tell where did you find the book in English translation? I have but in Hindi.

Comment: the book which I read was `Swara Yoga` The Tantric Science of Brain Breathing by `Swami Muktibodhananda`
It has the original Sanskrit text and English Translation of course